# Writing Spring boot's entities with kotlin, class vs data class for JPA

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jpa, entity, data-class

I would like to understand the best practices in creating Kotlin entities with JPA.

First, this is a part of my `build.gradle.kts`. I have added both `plugin.jpa` and `plugin.allopen`

```
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.5.3"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.10"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.5.21"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.5.21"
    kotlin("plugin.allopen") version "1.5.21"
}

allOpen {
    annotations("javax.persistence.Entity", "javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass", "javax.persistence.Embedabble")
}
```

Second, here it is my entity:

```kotlin
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
class UserEntity(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Int,
    @Column(name = "name")
    val name: String,
    @Column(name = "mail")
    val mail: String,
    @Column(name = "password")
    val password: String,
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", nullable = false)
    var role: RoleEntity
)
```

My questions are:

1. In this case, should I use `class` or `data class` for entities?
2. Should I override `equals()` and `hashcode()`?
3. In this case, I have no warning from IDE that I need to override `equals()` and `hashcode()`, but when I modify it to `data class`, I get this message:
   `The data class implementations of equals(), hashCode() and toString() are not recommended for JPA entities. They can cause severe performance and memory consumption issues.` but also it follows with this message `Generate equals() and hashcode() and toString()`. This is what I didn't understand, Why the IDE tells me to override them, usually these methods are necessary with `class` not `data class`, then why I get the warning only when I convert the class to `data class`?
4. Is it better to use var or val for entities?
5. Is it better to use nullable or non-nullable properties?

Thank you

Comment: Use `class`. As the warning states the `equals`/`hashCode` and `toString` generated for `data classes` (and records as well and Lombok `@Data` classes) aren't suitable for JPA as they include everything from the `UserEntity`. So when comparing `UserEntity` with id 1 and name `foo` with `UserEntity` with id 1 and name `bar` (because of a name change) JPA will not detect that they are the same (while they actually are). Fields are modifable so making them `val` would disable modification, nullability depends on the field.

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you for your answer, one more question, should I override hashCode() and equals()?  Or it's okay to leave my entity class without it?

Comment: For JPA you need to override it and implement a proper implementation. See https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-jpa-entity-identifier/